# Number of homomorphisms $ \phi: _4 \to _4 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I am trying to find the number of homomorphisms $ \phi: _4 \to _4 $ (where $_4$ is the dihedral group with $2\cdot4=8$ elements).

I know that $ _4 $ is generated by the $6$ transpositions ${(12),(13),(23),(14),(24),(34)}$  and a homomorphism is determined by the generators. Moreover, ${\rm ord}(\phi(a)) $ must divide ${\rm ord}(a) $. Hence, the order of the image of any generator is either $2$ or $1$. There are $4$ elements of order $2$ in $D_4$. But here is where I get stuck.

How do these observations help me find the total number of such homomorphisms?

Comment: I think you meant $ord(\phi(a))$ divides $ord(a)$. You can define a homomorphism by simply telling where the generators of $S_4$ are mapped to. They can only be mapped to elements whose orders divide 2 (then of order 2 or trivial). You can just count how many possibilities there are (note that two different generators can be mapped to the same element).

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected the mistake. As there are $4$ elements of order $2$ and one element of order $1$ in $D_4$, can I conclude that there are $5^6$ such homomorphisms since each generator may be mapped to any of these five elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before looking at the generators, first observe that some elements must map to the identity!

Because $D_4$ has no elements of order $3$, every $3$-cycle must map to the identity. Moreover, every $2$-$2$-cycle can be written as a product of $3$-cycles (e.g. $(12)(34) = (123)(234)$), so any product of transpositions must also go to $0$.

Next, the kernel of $\phi$ must be a normal subgroup of $S_4$. The only normal subgroups of $S_4$ are $S_4, A_4, V_4$ and the identity subgroup. We've just seen that $V_4 = \{1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ has to map to the identity. Hence, by the first isomorphism theorem, any homomorphism
$$\phi: S_4\to D_4$$
automatically factors through $S_4/V_4 \cong S_3$. Hence, it is completely equivalent to count the homomorphisms $S_3\to D_4$.

But now, $C_3\subset S_3$ maps to the identity, so a homomorphism $S_3\to D_4$ factors through $S_3/C_3\cong C_2$.

We are left with counting the number of homomorphisms
$$C_2\to D_4,$$
or equivalently, the number of elements of order dividing $2$ in $D_4$.

Since the map $S_4 \to C_2$ is obtained by quotienting by $A_4$, we deduce that all maps $S_4\to D_4$ take all non-transpositions to the identity and all transpositions to an element of order $2$ in $D_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = \phi(12)$. As you have noted, this is either the identity, or one of the five order-2 elements of $D_4$.

Consider $\phi(23)$. Since $(12)(23)$ has order $3$, the element $\phi((12)(23))$ must have either order $3$ (impossible), or be the identity. Thus $\phi(23) = \phi(12)^{-1} = a$. A similar argument shows that all the other four transpoositions must also be mapped to $a$.

How many candidates for homomorphisms does this leave us with? Are all of these actually homomorphisms?

Comment: As there are six possibilities to map $(12)$ and the other five transpositions are all mapped to the same element as (12) is, we are left with six candidates for such homomorphisms.

Comment: @convergence Yup, that's exactly it. Now you need to check whether the resulting six homomorphism-like functions $S_4\to D_4$ are indeed homomorphisms. One of them is easy, the other five can be a bit tricky if you're not used to the concept of even and odd permutations.

Comment: Certainly, the mapping of all elements to $id$ is a homomorphism. Unfortunately, I am not uses to the concept of odd and even permutations.